# Google maps V2, Google Play Service Update

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm using Google Maps V2 in my app, but when I run it in a new phone, it always asks to update Google Play Services. And only when Google Play Services is updated on the phone, then the map on my app runs.
My question is, is there any way to use maps V2 without updating play service??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have Google Play Services on your device to use Google Maps V2.

> The Google Maps Android API v2 is distributed as part of the Google
>   Play services SDK.

[See docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=tr)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Google Play Services were there before the update, you may use the same (or lower) version of google-play-services_lib. For most cases this should not be a problem, because that APK is updated automatically to the latest version. One exception is you have to use 3.x version when supporting devices with Android 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and let me tell you there is no solution for that yet

**BUT**

to make your map run in more android phones you can compile your project with few older google play services libraries.

```html
//in project's Build.gradle:

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

change "play-services:9.0.0" to older versions and test your app:

```html
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.7.3'
}
```

You can see all play services versions [here](https://google-play-services.en.uptodown.com/android/old) .

i hope it help a bit.